# Variance of the Neyman estimator and Heteroskedastic Variance

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, heteroscedasticity

I am trying to show the last equality with steps:

Where, Wi is the treatment status and the treated sample is Nt, while the control sample is Nc.

[image]

I cannot find my through it.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: V-hetero is the variance of the sample mean difference between treated and controls in a T-test? and $\hat{\epsilon}$ is the residual from the adjusted (two mean) analysis, or the unadjusted (one mean) analysis?

Comment: V-hetero is the expression after first equality sign, epsilon is the residual from a regression of Y on. W (the treatment status).